# How to use swagger-editor and swagger-codegen docker images together in offline enviroment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I work in an offline environment and want to setup an instance of swagger-editor to share with the rest of the team. I want to leverage the swagger-codegen capabilities similarly to how https://editor.swagger.io/ has the "Generate Server" and "Generate Client" menu options.

I used the docker images from [swagger editor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor) and [swagger-generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)  but can't find any working combination of parameters to get the editor and the generator working offline.

I tried using a docker-compose from https://github.com/spudmashmedia/swagger-complete-selfhosted.git but this did not work for me either.

Is there a way to pass the URL of the generator to the editor?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you managed to connect them?